# Serial Communication via Bluetooth on COM port

Tags: java, python, bluetooth, arduino, jssc

I was trying to create a Java program which communicates with a Bluetooth module (attached to SPARKI). I'm using [JSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) for the serial communication. The Bluetooth module is connected to my Windows 7 x64 PC on `COM8` port. The robot is also connected to my PC via usb on `COM12` port.

The following code snippet reveals, as expected, that there are 2 ports available: `COM8` and `COM12`

```
String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

for (String port : portNames) {
    System.out.println(port);
}
```

But when I try to open `COM8` using `new SerialPort("COM8").openPort();` it throws `SerialPortException: Port not found`

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I found articles for similar problem on Linux. The solutions were asking to change the permissions on the serial port. I don't think its possible on Windows.

Note: I'm also willing to change my programming language to either Python or C/C++ if that works out.

Comment: Have you tried to run as admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As wenzul said try running it as admin, open an elevated command prompt (search cmd, right click, select run as admin).

Comment: I was ready to give up .. and man do i feel stupid. Thank you Ruturaj/Wenzul.